# NodePython? Has someone ported NodeJS to Python? Or does a NodeJS-like platform exist in Python?

Tags: python, node.js

Is there a way to write NodeJS-like programs but using 100% Python?

I've found several references regarding connecting Python to NodeJS but am wondering if there is a native Python platform that scales as well as NodeJS?

Comment: 100% Python version of a Javascript library? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense, refine your question?

Comment: You mean like Twisted?

Comment: Exactly!  Twisted is exactly what I was looking for--thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a Node.js-like platform in 100% Python.